# In BigQuery, remove rows that are duplicated on every column besides one

Tags: google-bigquery

When removing duplicate rows in bigquery using multiple columns, a common solution is to use `row_number()` and partition by the multiple columns that are being removed. In our circumstance, we have a wide table (30 columns) and want to remove duplicates based on the uniqueness of 29 of these columns:

```
with
  t1 as (
    select 1 as a, 2 as b, 3 as c, 4 as d, 5 as e, 6 as f, 7 as g, 8 as h, 9 as i union all
    select 2 as a, 3 as b, 3 as c, 4 as d, 5 as e, 6 as f, 7 as g, 8 as h, 9 as i union all
    select 3 as a, 4 as b, 3 as c, 4 as d, 5 as e, 6 as f, 7 as g, 8 as h, 9 as i union all
    select 4 as a, 5 as b, 3 as c, 4 as d, 5 as e, 6 as f, 7 as g, 8 as h, 9 as i union all
    select 5 as a, 6 as b, 3 as c, 4 as d, 5 as e, 6 as f, 7 as g, 8 as h, 9 as i union all
    select 6 as a, 2 as b, 3 as c, 4 as d, 5 as e, 6 as f, 7 as g, 8 as h, 9 as i
  )
```

In the table above, we want to remove duplicates considering all columns except for column `a`. Therefore, rows 1 and 6 are duplicates and we want to remove either one, preferably removing the row with the higher value in column `a`, so row 6 in this example. Is this possible to do without using `row_number() over (partition by b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,...)`

Answer (score 0):

You may consider below query

```sql
 SELECT * 
   FROM t1 
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
          PARTITION BY TO_JSON_STRING((SELECT AS STRUCT t1.* EXCEPT(a)))
              ORDER BY a ASC
        ) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
select any_value(t).* replace(max(a) as a)
from your_table t
group by to_json_string((select as struct * except(a) from unnest([t])))
```

with output

[image]